# cannot redirect ui-router state

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, angular-ui-router, apache-tiles

**EDIT** I'm trying to use the ui-router, but i cannot get it work... i followed loads of tutorial, questions... i don't know what i'm missing. Here you have some hints, hopefully someone can give me some light [Browser data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3ShJ.jpg)

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module("home", ['ui.router']);  

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
            .state('introduccion', {
                url : "/",
                templateUrl : "views/introduccion.html",
                controller : "views/IntroduccionController"
            })
}]);
```

The src folder [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4buDv.png) is the following, maybe, i'm not implementing correctly the framework... i'll upload a jsfiddle asap,

Comment: It's tough to describe why it "doesn't work" right now since your code is broken regardless; I can't guarantee if your IIFE will ever execute to begin with.

Comment: just provide a jsfiddle or a plnkr of you code.......

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Did you include every JS file in the index? so much can go wrong here...

Comment: Sorry, i thought i uploaded the image... i just did it. I'm not having any errors, when i click on the "Change view" text it does nothing. I have a service js also, but it doesn't have any relation in here, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably forgetting to add [ui-view](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view/) to your `index.html` file:

```
<body>
  <a ui-sref="introduccion">introduccion</a>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

See a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iAhpTgwACrNochHFDU1U?p=preview).

Comment: i saw your plunker, it helped me.. but i can't see any differences between my html code and yours, what do you think? @drbishop, in your Plunker, you can click on the <a>.. tag, but in mine, i cannot do that.